# Why are the permissions on /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as set to 750?

Tags: permissions, compiling, assembler

Compiling a simple program in Ubuntu 16.04 with `gcc-5.4.0`:

```
$ cat tmp.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Yields the following error when trying to compile as a non-privileged user:

```
$ gcc tmp.c
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Permission denied
```

If I look at the permissions of the assembler, `as`:

```
$ ls -lt /usr/bin/as

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Aug 30 09:39 /usr/bin/as -> x86_64-linux-gnu-as

$ ls -lt /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as

-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 369480 Aug 30 09:39 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as
```

This is very strange.  I can compile this program as root without the error.

QUESTION:

Why is the assembler have 750 permissions?  How would it have gotten into this state. I can't imagine that Ubuntu comes like this by default.

Comment: It likely would have gotten into that state by careless use of the `chmod` command. Perhaps time to reinstall the `binutils` package?

Comment: I ran into this same issue on a _new_ Ubuntu 18.04.3 system, so it's not just the accidental misuse of `chmod` and it's not just Ubuntu 16.04. As a result, non-root users are getting `/usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied`.  ```# namei -om /usr/bin/gcc
...
 lrwxrwxrwx root root gcc -> gcc-7
   lrwxrwxrwx root root gcc-7 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7
     -rwxr-x--- root dev  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7
```. This is so strange to me. Does anyone know why it doesn't have o+x permissions?

Comment: I guess my issue is slightly different since mine is about `gcc` rather than `as` that the OP had, but very similar.
For comparison, `g++` _is_ runnable by any user. `namei -om` => `-rwxr-xr-x root root x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7`. 
And ```$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
$ which gcc
# nothing
```